# Opscode Chef Knife

Tags: chef-infra, knife

After about 6 hours of working on this - no luck. I have had no luck in doing even one of the most basic things with Opscode Chef. I need to use knife in my terminal and the command doesn't exist. I am not sure how to install it and there is not one drip, dabble, drop of documentation on it anywhere. All documentation starts with it, doesn't say how to actually install knife.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really wonder why you were not able to find documentation on knife. There are a ton of resources on knife setup. Check below link to start with:

1. [Install Chef 11.x on a Workstation](http://docs.opscode.com/install_workstation.html)
2. [Chef: Workstation Quick Setup](http://www.nineproductions.com/chef-workstation-quick-setup/)
3. [knife.rb](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/knife_rb.html)

Comment: At least the first one should help

Comment: This is also useful: https://learnchef.opscode.com/quickstart/workstation-setup/

Answer (score 2):

```
gem install chef
```

Will install chef (including the `knife` executable) for you.